# How to play specific sound to speaker when motions detected at specific time?

Tags: security, smart-home

[image]

If motion 1,2,3 detected at midnight, I would like to play [this sound](https://www.bunlongheng.com/sound/police-2) to my deck speaker and flash my smart bulb red (on repeat).

What is the basic way to achieve this?

Tools:

Samsung SmartThings hub, sensor and bulb. Speaker just basic 3.5mm jack aux in or RCA.

Comment: I believe this should be migrated to [iot.se]. On topic: "controlling, automating and sensing the environment using electronics ('smart devices')" and "consumer technology used for home automation". I've flagged it to be migrated.

Comment: This sounds like a Arduino or other type of micro controller project.

Comment: Or maybe involving IFTTT on a cell phone?

Comment: If it is still available look at some X10 modules.

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing what your motion detector, smart bulb and deck speaker are.

Comment: Samsung SmartThings hub, sensor and bulb. Speaker just basic 3.5mm jack aux in or RCA.